# How to make truly single spaced bullet items in Keynote

Tags: keynote

Although I have selected

> Spacing 1.0 - single

[image]

in the **Text Style**, we can see that there is still large space between each bullet item. How to compact them?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Notice the disclosure arrow "▶︎" beside **Spacing**?  There you can reveal the paragraph spacing.

[image: Spacing settings Keynote]

Change the **Before Paragraph** and **After Paragraph** to 0 pt or the desired amount.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So glad that helped!  Those disclosure arrows are easy to overlook.